# WPA Supplicant build on Wince6.0

Tags: user-interface, windows-ce, porting, ndis, wpa-supplicant

I want to build wpa supplicant for wince.                                     As a newbie don't know how much efforts it will take ?
What are the major thing i want to consider before entering into porting ?
I think its working for windows xp so can use existing ndis driver interface for wince 6.0.
How to disable Windows zero config from wince registry ?
Is there a way that wzc ui can use wpa supplicant instead of native supplicant?

Advises are appreciated..

Regards
Aswin

Answer (score 2):

You can disable WZC by adding this in your platform.reg file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\BuiltIn\ZeroConfig]
    "Dll"=-
    "Flags"=-
    "Index"=-
    "Order"=-
    "Prefix"=-
```

As far as I know there is no way to use the WZC ui with a different supplicant.

As for building wpa-supplicant, I cannot say how much effort is needed to compile it on CE. I chose to make my own supplicant using wpa-supplicant's and some Platform Builder code as reference, but for you it may be faster to try to compile it.

Hope this helps,
Dragan